# What was Han Solo thinking upon Leia's revelation on Endor about Luke?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, return-of-the-jedi, han-solo

At the end of RotJ, Han was about to concede to Luke over Leia and was giving her his blessings when Leia revealed that Luke was actually just her brother. What did Han think and feel upon that revelation?

Comment: "Wha- *Score.*"

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here https://youtu.be/lQDvsf5lAp0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### He’s surprised and pleased

In canon, he appears to have experienced surprise, followed by distinct happiness.

> “Oh. No, it’s not like that at all. He’s my brother.”
>
> “Oh,” says Han, then pauses to think what this means. And then pauses
> a little longer to think what it all means. “Oh!”
>
> And they kiss. And it is such a meaningful kiss, such a passionate
> kiss, that I’m relieved to say that it is soon interrupted by Wicket
> hurling himself at them with an ecstatic “Meeeercheeewawaaaa!!!!”
>
> <sub>*Beware the Power of the Dark Side!*</sub>

Moving down the canonicity ladder to Legends novelizations, he is said to have been "stunned, embarrassed, and elated."

> Then she realized what he was talking about. ‘Oh, no. No,’ she
> laughed, ‘it’s not like that at all - Luke is my brother.’
>
> Han was successively stunned, embarrassed, and elated. This made
> everything fine, just fine.
>
> <sub>*Return of the Jedi*</sub>

Comment: From the junior novel - *Leia realized Han’s misunderstanding and said, “Oh. No, it’s not like that at all.” She leaned closer to Han and said, “He’s my brother.” **Han was stunned by this news**. Leia smiled, and they embraced*

Comment: @Valorum - Sure. That seems generally consistent with the other two treatments.

Comment: @Adamant yes because kissing gives you cooties and that does not make for a happy ending.